# Is there any other way to add program to cgroups-v2 instead of giving their pids?

Tags: debian, cgroups

I am trying to learn cgroups-v2 and practicing it. [cgroups-v2 document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/using-cgroups-v2-to-control-distribution-of-cpu-time-for-applications_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel) stated that entering pid is the only way to add a program to cgroups-v2. Is there any other way to add a program's executables to cgroups-v2?

i.e instead of doing this :

```
echo "34578" > /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/tasks/cgroup.procs
```

can I do that for executable file like :

```
echo "/usr/bin/firefox/firefox >  /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/tasks/cgroup.procs
```

Do I have to know each time what is the pid of the program to control its resources? (*Also I found that the similar thing can be done by **systemd-run** in [systemd-run solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/fbfc6w/how_to_wrap_my_firefox_process_in_a_cgroup_to/) but, since I tried to learn cgroups-v2, it is out of topic*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to know the PID.

You could, for example have, 20 different `/bin/sh` processes running, and they would need to be in different cgroups. Dividing among the executable files hence would make little sense, practically!

It's easy to figure out the PID of something that is running only once, however:

```bsh
pidof firefox > /sys/fs/cgroup/Example/tasks/cgroup.procs
```

will do what you say you want. It's questionable it's actually what you need, though, as firefox (and other browsers alike) do spawn multiple processes.